# PowerShell Copy item from server to remote PC that is turned on but not logged on

Tags: powershell

I need to copy an image from a share on a server to multiple PCs. Most of them will have users logged on but there a select few which will be turned on but with no one logged onto the machine. I have run a test to try and copy the image but get an error saying "the network path was not found". So i am wondering if there is a way to copy the image to these machines that haven't got users logged onto them.

Here is my code, it's quite simple

```
copy-item -path "\\Server\file\image.png" -destination \\ComputerName\c$\Temp\ -Force
```

Comment: As long as the machine is on and the sharing is running it does not matter who, if anybody, is signed in. There is nothing special about that path that is dependent on a user being present. What is your source and target OS? Depending on where this goes this might be a question better fit for superuser.se

Comment: Does C:\Temp exists on those computers? Since you're using the administrative C$ share, are you administrator of those computers?